# How do I use gshuf or python in the terminal to randomly shuffle files in a folder on mac os?

Tags: python, macos, random, terminal, shuffle

I am trying to randomly shuffle the files in a folder on my mac. I came across a suggestion to use gshuf (part of coreutils), but I don't know exactly what command to enter.

First I tried going into the folder and typing gshuf, and that didn't seem to do anything so I hit control-c to exit. Then I tried gshuf and the folder path, and I got an error:

```
gshuf /Users/xxx
gshuf: read error: Is a directory
```

Anyone know how to make it work?
Can I use python in the terminal to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try using `-e` for `ECHO` which treat each `ARG` as an input.

You can read the manual by:

```
$ man K- shuf
```

Comment: Thanks Talha Junaid for cleaning up my answer - how did you do that formatting magic? :)